# ContentChildren class selector

Tags: angular

I have two components in Angular like this

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'content-com',
      template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
    })
    class ContentComponent {
        // Select all the elements with .grouped css class
        @ContentChildren('.grouped') grouped;
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'main-com',
      template: `<content-com>
        <div class="grouped"></div>
        <div class="grouped"></div>
      </content-com>`
    })
    class MainComponent {
    }
```

Is it possible to select all the Content Children using a css selector (in my case class selector) ? If not, what is the best approach to do it ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this by creating a directive. Let's call it `Class` with selector `[class]`, string Input bound to 'class' and hostbinding on the input variable also bound to `'class'`.

Then do `@ContentChildren(Class, {descendants: true, read: ElementRef})` and filter that [`QueryList`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/QueryList-class.html) for the specific classes you are interested in.

Here is the revised snippet:

> Also See [Plunker working here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LKdeSAkQquNgDEU4CRtR)

```js
// Remember to declare this in Module 
@Directive({selector: '[class]'})
class Class  { 
  @HostBinding('class') @Input('class') className: string = '';    
}

@Component({
  selector: 'content-com',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
class ContentComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  // Select all the elements with .grouped css class
  @ContentChildren(Class, {descendants: true, read: ElementRef}) classes: QueryList<ElementRef>; // <--- Note This change 

  get grouped() {
    if ( this.classes && this.classes.length ) {
      return this
        .classes
        .map((elRef:ElementRef):Element => elRef.nativeElement)
        .filter( (element: Element) => element.className == "grouped" );
    }
    
    return [];
  }
  
  ngAfterContentInit(){

      console.log( this.grouped ); // <-- expect (2) [div.grouped, div.grouped]    

  }
}
```

Comment: Note: this is the mechanism used by angular material `matTabContent` directive https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/tabs/tab-content.ts https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

Answer (score 14):

You can do it easier, without creating directive. What you have to know is that the selector for ContentChildren has to be variable name. So:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'content-com',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
class ContentComponent {
    @ContentChildren('grouped') grouped: QueryList<ElementRef>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'main-com',
  template: `<content-com>
    <div class="grouped" #grouped></div>
    <div class="grouped" #grouped></div>
  </content-com>`
})
class MainComponent {
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for me, `@ContentChildren`'s result is empty

Comment: @philr The ```@ContentChildren```'s result is available in ```ngAfterContentInit```. Maybe you're trying to access it too early.

Comment: This is not querying by class, this is querying using `#grouped`

Comment: Interesting but doesn't work when "#grouped" reference is not defined on the direct parent but a level upper in the tree (nested ng-content), which is what I am looking for

Comment: You shouldn't declare #grouped two times in one template. Template ref variable should be unique within one template. `The scope of a reference variable is the entire template. So, don't define the same variable name more than once in the same template as the runtime value will be unpredictable.` https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars

Comment: @Nickon - I thought exactly the same thing when I saw this but emprically this does actually work. If you use the same template variable multiple times, `@ContentChildren` returns an array. What I can't tell - and Angular doesn't seem to document is whether this is by design or a bug. Unless I can confirm that I would / will be wary to use it